# Dependency issues with Rubygems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a gem that has some dependency. I published that gem on Rubygems.org. My gem gets installed on other system, but the gem package is not located. I figured out that this is likely due to my gem dependency not getting installed. Do I need to do any specific thing to get all my dependency installed?

Comment: Can you link your gem? If it's on github that would especially be helpful

Comment: It's Private repository.. If you want .gemspec structure to check i can give you that

Comment: I'm no expert but here's another gem. Note how they require dependencies (both dev and not) https://github.com/traitify/traitify-ruby/blob/master/traitify.gemspec

Comment: Thanks ...One more query related to this What is the difference between add_dependancy , add_runtime_dependency & add_development_dependency..

Comment: `add_runtime_dependency` and `add_dependancy` are actually the same. It just adds the gem you specify as a dependency. The `add_development_dependency` only uses the installs dependency if it is a development environment (possibly for debugging)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at existing gems I see these components: Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, and whatever.gemspec. Note the gem name is lowercase to match the gemspec file name (I think this was a problem for me before)

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Specify your gem's dependencies in whatever.gemspec
gemspec
```

whatever.gemspec

```
Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "whatever"
  spec.add_dependency "hashie"
end
```

Comment: Thanks i was having add_development_dependency that's why it was not working properly I replace that with add_dependency ...Now it works :)